# Dumping mod_perlified variables--what's the local namespace?

Tags: winapi, namespaces, mod-perl2, mod-perl-registry

I have a mod_perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use 5.010001;

my $face = 'ugly';

use Data::Dump qq(pp);
die pp($ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::C_3a_www_test_2epl::face);
```

It dies `undef at C:/www/test.pl line 8.`

I was expecting `"ugly" at C:/www/test.pl line 8.`

If instead I

```
die pp(%ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::C_3a_www_test_2epl::);
```

...after restarting the service to clear any cached variables, `face` is not even listed.

I could have sworn this code was working the last time I used it...I wrote a whole `die` hook around this way of naming local variables so that I could get at certain local variables to dump debug information.

What's the local namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only variables shared using `our` are accessible this way.